# ¿Cómo validar de acuerdo al año escolar de datos de Textbox y 2 DateTimePicker C#?

Tags: c#

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNggz.png]

Busco validar 2 DateTimePicker que vendrian a ser FECHA_INICIO y FECHA_FINAL de acuerdo a un texbox que seria AÑO_ESCOLAR,todo esto en el lenguaje de programación c#.

Agregue este código al evento validating para validar que los datos ingresados en el campo fecha_inicio y fecha_fin sean coherentes.

Pero me di cuenta que  después de ingresar algún año a la caja de texto año_escolar, se mandaba a guardar sin mostrar los filtros de error que ya valide en el evento validating , ahora lo que busco es que se pueda validar de acuerdo a la caja de texto año escolar para que los datos sean correctos y coherentes .

```
private void DtpFechaFin_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime fecha_1 = DateTime.Parse(dtpFechaInicio.Text);
    DateTime fecha_2 = DateTime.Parse(dtpFechaFin.Text);

    int res = DateTime.Compare(fecha_1, fecha_2);
    if (fecha_1 > fecha_2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("La fecha #1 no puede ser mayor a la fecha #2", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else if (fecha_2 < fecha_1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("La fecha #2 no puede ser menor a la fecha #1", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola jose. Que significa "validar"?. Puedes editar tu pregunta y describir mejor lo que necesitas? Tambien sería interesante ver si has probado algo

Comment: Para saber cómo validar un dato, lo primero que se necesita es saber cuál es la validación, la cuál no has añadido a tu pregunta.

Comment: Si, ya lo hice, ya edite .

Comment: No se si te entiendo exactamente. No te serviría hacer la misma comprobación que haces en el `Validating` en el evento click de `GUARDAR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la única validación que tienes que hacer es la que has mostrado y quieres que se realice en varias partes, lo que yo haría es una función a la cual llamaría cuando fuera necesario:

```
public bool ValidarFechas()
{
    DateTime fecha_1 = DateTime.Parse(dtpFechaInicio.Text);
    DateTime fecha_2 = DateTime.Parse(dtpFechaFin.Text);

    int res = DateTime.Compare(fecha_1, fecha_2);
    if (fecha_1 > fecha_2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("La fecha #1 no puede ser mayor a la fecha #2", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
    else if (fecha_2 < fecha_1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("La fecha #2 no puede ser menor a la fecha #1", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private void DtpFechaFin_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ValidarFechas();
}

private void BtnGuardar_Click(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(ValidarFechas())
    {
         // Continuar
    }
}
```